# How to change key binding for ERB tag in TextMate 2?

Tags: erb, textmate, textmate2

When I want to insert an ERB tag inside an .html.erb file in **TextMate 2**, the default key binding is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>. Pressing it several times cycles between <%= %>, <% %>, etc.

I would like to change it to <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. How can I achieve this? I have tried finding the key binding for ERB tags in "edit bundles..." but couldn't locate it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm trying to do this because I'm on a Swiss French keyboard and the default key binding is quite hard to use. I have set it to the desired key binding in Sublime Text 2 and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the bundle editor and look for Ruby->Menu Actions->Insert ERB's...

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for it in "Ruby on Rails". Also, in "other action", "Toggle ERB tag" needs to be changed. Perfect, thank you.